# Pandas DataFrame Create a Column that holds a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I would like to take a list and create a new column in a pandas dataframe.  Here is the code which I have created, notice it will throw an error.

```
d={'range':list(range(0,100))}
print(d)
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

l=['var1','var2','var3']
print(df)
df['var_list']=l
```

The correct result would be a dataframe with 2 columns, the first being range, the second being a list of variables "var_list" which has a static value over all the rows.

Here is an example of the desired output:
[image]

In fact, it does not have to be a list if that is not possible to perform in a dataframe, it can be the values from the list in a string separated by a space or some delimiter.

Comment: Can you show an example of your input and output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little bit tricky

```
df['var_list'] = [l] * len(df)
df.head(4)
Out[333]: 
    range            var_list
0       0  [var1, var2, var3]
1       1  [var1, var2, var3]
2       2  [var1, var2, var3]
3       3  [var1, var2, var3]
```

Comment: Thanks much Wen, I figured it would be something really simple.

Comment: @Kyle Yw, basically, the back end mechanism, is the list of list each sub list will be recognized as a cell value :-)